# Adding vertical gripper to dialog

Tags: mfc

I am not sure what code to show you here. I have a `CDialogEx` derived resource in my MFC application:

[image: Gripper]

It supports the dynamic resize layout controls so the user can resize the window. But I would like to add a vertical gripper (indicated in red) so the user can make the width of the names column larger.

I have done some research on this and all the articles are nearly 10 years old and don't factor in the newer dynamic resizing controls.

---

Having researched this more I see that the "resize gripper" term is not what I mean. That is the icon in the bottom right. I don't mean this.

I am sure you know what I mean though. Is it possible?

Comment: The term you're looking for is a [tag:splitter], traditionally used in a CFrameWnd application via a [`CSplitterWnd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xttbe5t.aspx) rather than in a CDialog.

Comment: `CSplitterWnd` is the way to go, but if you have already finished the dialog, and you want to add resize/gripper thing, you have to create you own control. You would need to break your dialog in to two child dialogs, and the gripper tells the child dialogs to resize themselves.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani OK. Seems like too much work. Think I will leave it. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a custom gripper control can be relatively easy. See `CMySplitter` class below.

But if all the controls are in one dialog, it will be very difficult reposition/resize individual controls one by one.

Ideally, use two child dialogs. Set the resize/reposition properties for individual controls in resource editor. Put the grip control in between the two dialogs and resize in response.

Class for gripper control:

```
#include <functional>

class CMySplitter : public CStatic
{
public:
    class CPopup : public CWnd
    {
    public:
        CMySplitter *parent;
        int offset;
        void OnMouseMove(UINT flag, CPoint pt);
        void OnLButtonUp(UINT flag, CPoint pt);
        DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    };

    std::function<void(int)> callback;
    CRect boundary;
    CPopup popup;
    void OnLButtonDown(UINT flag, CPoint point);
    void PreSubclassWindow();
    void SetRange(int left, int right);
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

//create splitter control from a static control in dialog
void CMySplitter::PreSubclassWindow()
{
    CStatic::PreSubclassWindow();

    //modify static control's style (must have SS_NOTIFY)
    SetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE | SS_GRAYRECT | WS_CHILD | SS_NOTIFY);

    //create a popup window with transparency
    static CString classname =
        AfxRegisterWndClass(0, 0, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));
    popup.CreateEx(WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_PALETTEWINDOW | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE,
        classname, NULL, WS_POPUP, CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), this, 0);

    popup.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(0, 128, LWA_ALPHA);
    popup.parent = this;
}

//when user click the static control, show a popup window
void CMySplitter::OnLButtonDown(UINT flag, CPoint pt)
{
    CStatic::OnLButtonDown(flag, pt);

    GetCursorPos(&pt);

    CRect rc;
    GetWindowRect(&rc);

    popup.offset = pt.x - rc.left;
    popup.SetWindowPos(NULL, rc.left, rc.top, rc.Width(), rc.Height(), SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    popup.SetCapture();
}

//how far to the left and right the splitter can go
void CMySplitter::SetRange(int left_, int right_)
{
    CRect rc;
    GetParent()->GetWindowRect(&rc);
    boundary.left = rc.left + left_;
    boundary.right = rc.right - right_;
}

//move this popup window
void CMySplitter::CPopup::OnMouseMove(UINT flag, CPoint pt)
{
    CWnd::OnMouseMove(flag, pt);
    GetCursorPos(&pt);
    CRect rc;
    GetWindowRect(&rc);

    int x = pt.x - offset;
    if (x > parent->boundary.left && x < parent->boundary.right)
        SetWindowPos(NULL, x, rc.top, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);
}

//hide popup window, let the parent dialog know
void CMySplitter::CPopup::OnLButtonUp(UINT flag, CPoint pt)
{
    CWnd::OnLButtonUp(flag, pt);
    ReleaseCapture();
    ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);

    CRect rc;
    GetWindowRect(&rc);
    parent->callback(rc.left);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMySplitter::CPopup, CWnd)
    ON_WM_CREATE()
    ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
    ON_WM_LBUTTONUP()
    ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMySplitter, CWnd)
    ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Usage:

Add a static control with `IDC_STATIC1` to the dialog and use as follows.

The code below has a main dialog `CMyDialog` with `IDD_DIALOG`, normal dialog

It has two child dialogs, child1 and child2 with `IDD_PAGE1` and `IDD_PAGE2`

`IDD_PAGE1` and `IDD_PAGE2` are dialog resources with "child" style (not popup)

```
class CMyDialog : public CDialogEx
{
public:
    class CChild1 : public CDialogEx
    {
    };

    class CChild2 : public CDialogEx
    {
    };

    CChild1 child1;
    CChild1 child2;

    //respond to gripper resize
    void respond(int position)
    {
        CRect rs;
        m_splitter.GetWindowRect(&rs);
        rs.MoveToX(position);
        ScreenToClient(&rs);

        CRect rc;
        GetClientRect(&rc);

        CRect r1(0, 0, rs.left, rc.bottom);
        CRect r2(rs.right, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom);

        child1.MoveWindow(r1, TRUE);
        child2.MoveWindow(r2, TRUE);
        m_splitter.MoveWindow(rs, TRUE);

        m_splitter.Invalidate(TRUE);
    }

    CMySplitter m_splitter;
    BOOL OnInitDialog()
    {
        CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
        child1.Create(IDD_PAGE1, this);
        child2.Create(IDD_PAGE2, this);

        m_splitter.SubclassDlgItem(IDC_STATIC1, this);
        m_splitter.SetRange(50, 50);
        m_splitter.callback = std::bind(&CMyDialog::respond, this, std::placeholders::_1);

        //width for splitter
        int dx = 10;

        CRect rc;
        GetClientRect(&rc);
        CRect r1(0, 0, 200, rc.bottom);
        CRect r2(r1.right + dx, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom);
        CRect rs(r1.right, 10, r2.left, rc.bottom - 10);

        child1.MoveWindow(r1);
        child2.MoveWindow(r2);
        m_splitter.MoveWindow(rs);

        child1.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
        child2.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

        return TRUE;
    }
    ...
};
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But I don’t know how to add two child dialogs and this would potentially break all the code I already have. What is involved with having child dialogs?

Comment: Yes you have to break your dialog in to 3 parts. A main dialog with menu, and 2 child dialogs. I made changes to `CMyDialog` to show an example. Most dialog boxes don't have this type of capabilities, it's probably not worth the added complexity. I added an answer for the sake of answering.